# Making random string in c#

Tags: c#, random

How can I to make a random string with C#??

I tried this:

```cs
Random randomnumber = new random();
Var myrandomnumber = random.next(1, 4);

String [] words = {"ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"};
Console.writeline($"computer:{myrandomnumber}");
```

Comment: What is the result of when you run this?

Comment: `WriteLine` is case sensitive and you forgot to access your `string[]` array

Comment: you mean`{words[myrandomnumber - 1]}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to pick one random item from an array.Try the code below:

```
static class Program
{
    static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] words = {"ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"};
        int index = rng.Next(words.Length);
        string item = words[index];

        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

It uses a single instance of `Random` to generate a random index of the array.

If you want to generalize this process then you can define a simple extension method

```
    public static T PickRandom<T>(this T[] array)
    {
        return array[rng.Next(array.Length)];
    }
```

Furthermore, if you wanted to shuffle the array (re-arrange the order randomly) then use this extension method:

```
    public static void ShuffleArray<T>(this T[] array, int repeats = 1)
    {
        for (int iter = 0; iter < repeats; iter++)
        {
            Array.Sort(array, (x, y) => 2 * rng.Next(2) - 1);
        }
    }
```